# Pull Soundcloud track list with no autentication

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I would like to pull a certain user tracklist and display it. Now i am manning to do this but i always need to connect(by pressing the link) is there a way where i eliminate this step or a way to be always authenticated. I have re-searched this on soundcloud api but with no success, and i dont get why authentication is needed when im accessing public data.

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();
require 'Soundcloud.php';

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('MY_CLIENT_ID', 'MY_SECRET', 'http://www.ericmlt.com/MarcKane/soundcloud/');
$soundcloud->setDevelopment(FALSE);

$authURL = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();

echo "<a href='$authURL'>Connect to Soundcloud</a>";

//Attempt to get token from Session first
//Set the token otherwise..

try {

    $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['access_token'] ;
}  else {
    $soundcloud->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
try {
    $tracks = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks', array('user_id' => '857348')), TRUE);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

foreach ($tracks as $track){
    $trackID = $track['id'];
    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F'.$trackID.'"></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a list of tracks like this:

```
echo '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/users/857348"></iframe>';
```

Otherwise, if you need to retrieve the list of tracks and create widget for each of them (not really recommended) you could go with this (note I am not writing PHP a lot, but idea is to issue HTTP GET to the following URL):

```
$tracks_json = file_get_contents('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/857348/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);
foreach ($tracks as $track){
  $trackID = $track->id;
  echo '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F'.$trackID.'"></iframe>';
}
```

You don't really need to authenticate here.